# How to identify text related to a particular dynmamic value in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following 2 columns in my dataframe:

```
COL1    COL2

 12    :402:agshhhjd:45:hghghgruru:12:fghg,hgh:22:hhhh
 57    :42:ags,hhhjd:57:hghg,hgruru:120:fghgh,gh:12:hhhhhh
```

I need to create another column COL3 which sould be like below:

```
  COL1  COL2                                                    COL3

   12   :402:agshhhjd:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghg,hgh:22:hhhh       fghg,hg
   57   :42:agshhhjd:57:hghg,hgruru:120:fghghgh:12:hhhhhh      hghg,hg
```

The new column COL 3 needs to be created in such a way that it searches the value of COL1 in COL2 for the same row and then prints the 7 characters apart from the ":".  I tried doing is using slice, but its not working. can someone kindly help.

Comment: why does the second one have a comma??

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the attribute `replace`, but first you have to change the datatype of column 1. we need to replace everything that is in COL2 save the wordings after the number in COL1  ie:

`.*12:(\w{7}).*` So we just capture the seven letters and call them by back reference ie value  = \1. Also we do the same for the second row. This can be done easily done since `replace` is vectorized. Although this will be slow

```
df['COL3'] = df.COL2.replace(regex=r'.*'+ df.COL1.astype('str') +':(\\w{7}).*',value="\\1")

df 
   COL1                                               COL2     COL3
0    12  :402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghghgh,:22:hhhh  fghghgh
1    57  :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghghgruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:h...  hghghgr
```

You can also do:

```
import re
[re.sub(".*"+str(i)+":(\\w{7}).*","\\1",j) for i,j in zip(df.COL1,df.COL2)]
```

## EDIT

with your update, you could do:

```
  df.assign(COL3 = df.COL2.replace(regex=r'.*'+ df.COL1.astype('str')+':(.{7}).*',value="\\1"))
Out[102]: 
   COL1                                               COL2     COL3
0    12  :402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghg,hgh,:22:...  fghg,hg
1    57  :42:ags,hhhjd,:57:hghg,hgruru,:120:fghgh,gh,:1...  hghg,hg
```

Comment: This is not working and is giving me the same column,i.e. whole of COL2.

Comment: @sayan_sen which one is not working? it worked in the example given. It will not work in a row where there is no match, but you can use an or situation in the regex to delete the whole row

Comment: Every row has the corresponding matching value, still its not working..Its giving me the entire COL2,however I just want that part of column 2 which comes exactly after the match with COL1 and then 7 characters from then. Any help pls?

Comment: @sayan_sen even when running the example? or just when running it on the real data?

Comment: Running it on real Data which has a similar format like the example above.

Comment: @Onyamby: Edited the question now.Kindly help Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension and **`re.findall`**:

```
import re

df['COL3'] = [
    re.findall('{}\:([a-z]{{7}})'.format(i), j) for i, j in zip(df.COL1, df.COL2)
]

   COL1                                               COL2       COL3
0    12  :402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghghgh,:22:hhhh  [fghghgh]
1    57  :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghghgruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:h...  [hghghgr]
```

You could also use a list comprehension and **`split`**, although this will throw an error if the first value isn't found in `COL2`:

```
[j.split('{}:'.format(i))[1][:7] for i, j in zip(df.COL1, df.COL2)]
# ['fghghgh', 'hghghgr']
```

If you can guarantee that the value *will* be found in `COL2`, then using split is faster:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

%timeit [re.findall('{}\:([a-z]{{7}})'.format(i), j) for i, j in zip(df.COL1, df.COL2)]
28.3 ms ± 1.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [j.split('{}:'.format(i))[1][:7] for i, j in zip(df.COL1, df.COL2)]
12 ms ± 45.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [12, 57], 'Col2': [':402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghghgh,:22:hhhh', ':42:agshhhjd,:57:hghghgruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:hhhhhh']})

test


    Col1    Col2
0   12      :402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghghgh,:22:hhhh
1   57      :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghghgruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:h...

def my_val(col1num, col2text):

    # Split columns by ':'
    col2_ls = col2text.split(':')[1:]

    # Create an empty dict to store key-value pairs
    my_dict = {}

    # Create your key-value pairs and update dict
    for i, j in zip(range(0, len(col2_ls), 2), range(1, len(col2_ls)+1, 2)):
        my_dict[col2_ls[i]] = col2_ls[j]

    # If the key exists return the value
    if str(col1num) in my_dict.keys():
        val = my_dict[str(col1num)]
        return val
    else:
        return 'Unavailable'

test['Col3'] = test.apply(lambda x: my_val(col1num=x['Col1'], col2text=x['Col2']), axis=1)

test

    Col1    Col2                                                Col3
0   12      :402:agshhhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fghghgh,:22:hhhh   fghghgh,
1   57      :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghghgruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:h...   hghghgruru,
```

Hope this helps